# Apache Reverse Proxy Serving Wrong Content

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect, reverse-proxy, wordpress

I have an Apache Proxy setup in front of an HTTP daemon process that serves a Sinatra web application with the following Directives (which work great)

```
ProxyPass / http://ip-ad-dr-ess:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://ip-ad-dr-ess:8080/
```

This allows me to browse http://example.com and served the content from the daemon web server.
I would like to include a wordpress blog as a subdirectory to the main site.

```
http://example.com <- Sinatra
http://example.com/blog <- Wordpress
```

Here is the entire config section

```
<IfModule mod_proxy_http.c>
LogLevel debug
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass /blog http://blog.example.com:80/
ProxyPassReverse /blog http://blog.example.com:80/
ProxyPass / http://ip-ad-dr-ess:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://ip-ad-dr-ess:8080/
<Location />
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Protocol http
</Location>
<Location /blog>
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Protocol http
</Location>
ProxyPreserveHost on
ProxyErrorOverride Off
</IfModule>
```

The problem I am having is when I navigate to http://example.com/blog I am served content from   http://example.com not from the Wordpress.

As a test, in the config above I replaced http://blog.example.com:80/ with http://www.google.com:80/ and when I navigate to http://example.com/blog I am simply redirected to Google's site (with the URL in the address bar) which is not the behavior I expected.

Any idea of how I can resolve or maybe further debug this issue as to why the wordpress content is not be served?

Thanks

**Update blog.exmaple.com excerpt**

```
<VirtualHost ip-ad-dr-ess:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@blog.example.com
DocumentRoot /home/path/blog.example.com
ServerName www.blog.example.com
ServerAlias blog.example.com
DirectoryIndex index.html index.shtml index.htm Index.html Index.htm Index.shtml$
ErrorLog /home/path/logs/blog.example.com/http.20187367/error.log
Alias /stats /home/path/logs/blog.example.com/http.20187367/html
<Directory /home/path/logs/blog.example.com/http.20187367/html>
AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo Indexes Limit Options=ExecCGI,Includes,Indexes$
</Directory>
Alias /doc/analog /usr/share/analog
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  =www.blog.example.com       [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)         http://blog.example.com$1  [R=301,NE]
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Might be a dumb questsion, but does blog.example.com work as expected?

Also you should ommit the trailing slashes from the "http://blog.example.com:80/" or add one to the "/blog" before it

Comment: @cperrin88 the blog site does serve content as expected. I tried removing the trailing slashes, and the port number with the same result.

Comment: First of all blog.example.com needs to work correctly. If you put it in the browser on the server the blog should pop up. Otherwise the ReverseProxy can't do a thing.
Is the blog servered on the same host?

Comment: @cperrin88 Yes the blog does work, and it is served on the same host

Answer (score 2):

You should try adding a trailing slash the path "/blog" like this

```
ProxyPass /blog/ http://blog.example.com/
ProxyPassReverse /blog/ http://blog.example.com/
```

Comment: `http://example.com/blog` returns a 404 (from the example.com application) and `http://example.com/blog/` serves the content from the main site example.com/

Comment: The first error is normal because the resourcees /blog and /blog/ are different. You need to write a rewrite rule to send the /blog requests to /blog.
The Second error is more puzzling as you say that blog.example.com  works fine. I can't see the problem here. I guess the problem lies somewhere in the config of blog.examlpe.com.

Comment: Would you mind posting the config of blog.example.com

Comment: Yes, the issue is that `http://example.com` and `http://example.com/blob/` are rending the same content. Maybe seeing the live site will clear things up. `http://getdropstream.com` and `http://getdropstream.com/blog/`

Comment: Is there anything specific you want to see from `blog.example.com`?

Comment: Just a general overview. Add it to your post.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue. The root cause was that the I setup a proxy from one virtualhost to another on the same ip and the same port.

I changed the `blog.example.com` to listen on a different port, updated the proxy values in `http://example.com` which resolved the problem